# why can't pass the parameter in onclick function like this. Blue - #1da2c3

Tags: javascript, laravel

How we pass the onclick function parameter like this. (Blue - #1da2c3)

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" 
   style="background-color:#af828a;" 
   @if($split1[0] != $split[0]) 
      onclick="load_varient_color(**Blue - #1da2c3**);"
   @endif>
      {{$color}}
</a>
```

Comment: Try using quotes, `Blue - #1da2c3` is a string

Comment: What exactly do you want to pass as the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Try it,

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"
    style="background-color:#af828a;"
    @if($split1[0] != $split[0])
       onclick="load_varient_color('Blue - #1da2c3');"
    @endif>
       {{$color}}
 </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to pass "Blue - #1da2c3":

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" 
   style="background-color:#af828a;" 
   @if($split1[0] != $split[0]) 
      onclick="load_varient_color('Blue - #1da2c3');"
   @endif>
      {{$color}}
</a>
```

Or if you want to pass an object {blue: '#1da2c3'} then try this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" 
   style="background-color:#af828a;" 
   @if($split1[0] != $split[0]) 
      onclick="load_varient_color({{ json_encode(['blue' => '#1da2c3') }});"
   @endif>
      {{$color}}
</a>
```